# How to detect user has cancelled subscription?

Tags: android, cancellation, in-app-subscription

Suppose I applied this to go in-app subscription (testing) by applying this code :

```
        val builder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setSku(sPlan.sku).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
        val responseCode = playStoreBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, builder.build())
        println(responseCode)
```

And then I go google play subscription to cancel my subscription. After doing this, I see the subscription has ended. When I go back to the app, how I can retrieve the status of the user that I have cancelled my subscription ?

I cannot find the status about this

```
    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {


}
```

Anyway, I use

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
```

Even though I studies 2.0.0 version, there has no server implementation or any guidelines telling the app to detect changes of  the subscription  state

Answer (score 0):

Playstore provides realtime push notification with details of change of subscription status to your server through pub/sub.

You can follow below guides for to implement realtime push notification with your server.

[Add real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications)

Comment: Can I use mobile to fetch Android subscription record instead ?

Comment: Yes, you can try using rest API for subscription valication with Google PlayStore. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

Comment: Does the user need to consume the subscription after purchase ?

Comment: No, It is not necessary to consume subscription unless you are going to handle it manually.

Comment: Good to hear that play console have this functionality too.